# int value overwritten to zero sometimes

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code which works like this:

```
boolQwInterface::setSomething(const A& obj, const B& Name, int Val)
{
    bool ret=true;

    LOG_MSG(msg, SIZE, "writing: %s, %s, %d", dbPtr->getDbName(), Name.getRepr().c_str(), Val);

    if(WriteDB(dbPtr->getid(), obj.c_string(), Name.getRepr().c_str(), (void*)&Val)<0)
    {
        LOG_MSG(msg, SIZE, "failed: %s", Name.getRepr().c_str());
        ret=false;
    }
    ....
}
```

The problem is "Val" is getting overwritten to 0 even though the caller is passing some genuine value like 40 or so. Sometimes, it take the right value the caller passes(like 40 or so), otherwise it takes it as zero though a value of 40 is being passed to it.
Any thoughts on this? May be I should be passing by reference?

Comment: Does `dbPtr->getDbName()` return a `char*` or a `std::string&` (or something else)?

Comment: Also you should tell us at what point in the code the Val is corrupted.  Does LOG_MSG not give the expected output?  You should use print statements to find the line of code results in an unexpected change of Val and you should show us that line.

Comment: Please clarify the following, you call setSomething with Val as 40 (perhaps). LOG_MSG will output 40 as the value in the log. LOG_MSG uses pass by value for setSomething, or perhaps is a const reference. WriteDB sometimes edits the value of Val?

Comment: This seems strange to me. Do you want to access the new value of `Val` (presumably set by `WriteDB`) after `QwInterface::setSomething` exits? If so, you need to pass `Val` to `setSomething` by reference.

Comment: @David
You are right , its at the point when LOG_MSG does not give the right value which is expected just before WriteDb

Comment: @sharth
call setSomething with Val as 40 (perhaps). LOG_MSG will output 0 as the value in the log.

Comment: It sounds like there is either a bug in the code calling setSomething or a bug in LOG_MSG.  If you could give us a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example (http://sscce.org) we would probably spot the problem but I think you have omitted too much code from the question for us to tell what is going on.

Comment: @David I have pasted the code for the caller to setSomething, any clue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the answer box, since this is easier to describe with newlines.

The interesting part of your code can be reduced to:

```
bool setSomething(int Val) {
   FunctionOne(Val);
   FunctionTwo(&Val);
   ....
}
```

You really haven't given enough information to help you out all that much.

Comment: FunctionOne(Val); will print as 0 when setSomething is called with val = 40. Should setSomething be something like? bool setSomething(int &Val)
Because outside this setSomething function when we try to print this value it says 0!

Comment: Okay here is the caller for setSomething(....);


unsigned int val;

setSomething(name1, name2,

               static_cast<int>(val);